# How do I remove the font gap?

Tags: html, css

I have the follow CSS code, which results in a 12px gap above the text, and a 15px gap below the text.

I've tried setting padding and margin to `0px`, and also setting line-height.

**How can I make my text fit the div (with no gap)?**

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>THIS IS A TEST</div>
```

Comment: setting line-height should work

Answer (score 3):

If you highlight your text, you'll notice that the vertical padding is actually *part of the font*.

One solution would be to specify a `line-height`. (I've also included `padding-top` to offset the font's uneven vertical padding.)

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;

  line-height: 0.73em;
  padding-top: 0.03em;
}
```

```html
<div>THIS IS A TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of that gap using line-height as mentioned above, but it's important to realize that it's required in order to render many other characters that extend above or below the ones in your snippet.  If you remove it, this may result in rendering issues depending on the text content of your div:

For example, this:

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>TEST yqj ÑÜ</div>
```

Ends up like this:

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.023em;
  line-height: 0.73em;
}
```

```html
<div>TEST yqj ÑÜ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line height is the best option.

use     line-height:40px;

```css
.divclass {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em !important;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divclass">THIS IS A TEST</div>
```

}

adjust line height to achieve desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
      .test{  line-height: 0px; }
for removing line to line gap.

Use
        .test{  word-spacing: 0px;}
for removing word to word gap

and use 
         .test{  letter-spacing: 0px; }
for removing letter to letter gap